# overlapping segments

Tags: python, algorithm, list, comparison

i have a huge list of two-element tuples which are coordinates of segments (start, end). In this way in a list below

```
list = [ (1,4), (2, 3), (10, 20), (18, 45) ]
```

there are 4 segments with their start and end localization. I would like to remove segments that overlap. I expect to have a list like this as a result:

```
list = [ (1,4), (10,20) ].
```

I've already written a function which takes as input a pair of segments and returns 1 if their coordinates overlap:

```
def test_overlap(s1,e1,s2,e2):
    if (s1 <= e2 and e1 >= s2) or (e1 >= s2 and s1 <= e2):
        return 1
    if (s1 <= s2 and e1 >= e2) or (s1 >= s2 and e1 <= e2):
        return 1
```

But I have no idea how to compare efficiently each pair in a huge list of segments. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: is there a maximum size to the ranges?

Comment: How do you know that the correct output should not be [ (1,4), (18,45) ]?

Comment: @Aren no, it's not a homework, i'm trying to identify overlapping genes in human genome and these stat and stop coords are actual cordinates of genes. @gnibbler, yes, there is a maximum value: 400.

Comment: the correct answer is [], as every segment overlaps with at least one other segment

Comment: @recursive, i have a score value which is assigned to each segment, and i will always pick the one with higher score.

Comment: Just a quick not to your overlap function: this is much more elegant...:

    return (s1 < e2) and (s2 < e1)

Comment: @s_sherly: Sorry, it looked suspiciously like the simple problem-solving type-questions that usually end up as homework.

Comment: Underspecified problem? What do you return in the case [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)]?

Comment: @recursive @Paul Hankin Indeed, the problem is underspecified.  One reasonable interpretation would be: return any subset of intervals `S` such that 1) no two intervals in `S` overlap 2) any interval not in `S` overlaps with at least one interval in `S`.  In other words, return any maximal non-overlapping subset of intervals.

Comment: How do you choose which of the overlapping segments to discard and which to keep?

Answer (score 5):

There's a data structure designed for this exact purpose (efficient identification of interval overlaps), it's called [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 3):

First, sort the list (for comparison first use start point end then end point). Then go through list and remove all the tuples which are overlapping the previous element in the list. It is O(nlog(n)) for sorting and O(n) to go through the list.

Hope it helps.